# "JUST" or "EVEN"? "These days it is expensive to take care of just one child."

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

**"These days it is expensive to take care of just one child."**

When I read the sentence, I understand the point, however, I think "just" might be ambiguous here, so I think that instead of **"just"**, the word **"even"** sits better in the sentence, because **"...just one child"** can create a meaning like **".....you need have more than one",** can't it?

So, this is what I want to ask. What do you think? Should it not be **"even"** instead of **"just"** in the sentence?

**"These days it is expensive to take care of EVEN one child."**

Comment: Both are fine. 'Just one' can carry the implication of 'let alone more', and need not imply, as you suggest, 'you need to have more than one'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: It *might* be "obvious" which sense of ***just*** (***even*** or ***only***) is intended with OP's example. But not necessarily. As my answer indicates, even with this *exact* example there's scope for ambiguity. And I'm sure there will be many "similar" contexts where the ambiguity is even more problematic. So I still think ***just*** is a ***very*** bad choice for a non-native speaker to consider using here.

Comment: Why not both? These days it is expensive to take care of even just one child.

Comment: @Stef: Or the other meaningful "both" permutation - *These days it is expensive to take care of **only** just one child*. All three words are intensfiers, so if you use *two*, you're just making a more emphatic assertion. In your case, that one child is ***far too many***, in my case, that it's ***nowhere near enough***.  I'd say the third possible permutation *(**even + only**)* is "incomprehensible".

Comment: I agree that *just* is ambiguous - suggesting that there might be some [economy of scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economies_of_scale) in having more than one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In principle, ***just*** is a valid alternative to ***even*** in OP's context. But it's a *very bad choice*, because of the potential for misunderstanding. Note this *default* meaning...

> 1: *X is [bad, impossible, unsatisfactory] with **just** Y*  (OR *...with **only** Y*)
> means ***Y is not enough** [for X]* - ***more** [than just Y] **is needed***

Hence in OP's exact context, one could easily interpret the text as implying...

> *The **cost per child** of providing care is expensive with **just one child***

That's to say - "economies of scale" make it cheaper ***per child*** if you care for several children.

---

TL;DR: Avoid ***just*** and stick with ***even*** in the cited context.

Note that in "real" *(spoken)* language, ambiguity is unlikely because we put...

> heavy stress on ***just*** for the ***only*** sense (***more*** is better),
> OR
> heavy stress on ***one*** for the ***even*** sense (***less*** - i.e. *none* - is better).

Comment: "Even with ten children the cost-per-child was still too high."

Comment: @user3067860 "still" is doing the heavy lifting in that sentence, along with the implication that family size grows in one direction (upward).

Comment: @Flater "Even with 10 children per teacher the cost-per-child was too high."

Answer (score 9):

"Just", used adverbially, means *only* or *simply*, for example "*just one child*". You're most often to see it used with *one* of something as in your example of "just one child", but you can use it with any number to mean *no more than*, for example "*just the two of us*".

"Even", used adverbially, is to denote *the unexpected or extreme*, for example "*all children can struggle at school, even the most intelligent*".

If "one child" is the extreme end of your scale, then arguably you could use either, but 'even' seems the most appropriate because saying "it is expensive to care for just one child" could seem like you are saying that is the *only* circumstance under which it is expensive, whereas what I think you are trying to say is that if it is expensive to care for one then it must be *even more expensive* to care for more.

Comment: Yes, and for example the meanings of "I don't want to have just one child" and "I don't want to have even one child" are quite different.